# Shutdown on idle - Windows 10 Home

Tags: triggers, scheduled-tasks, shutdown

My First post so be please be nice. I've been digging at this for over 2 days or so.

I want my computer to shutdown down after being idle for 1 hour and it's proving surprisingly difficult.

What I've tried:

Firstly, I made a task on task scheduler which would (should) run program 'shutdown' with arguments /s /f /c "blah blah" triggered by 'on idle' with the condition: 'start the task only if the computer is idle for' 1 hour with 'wait for idle' set on 'Do not wait' (as, I think, the trigger is 'on idle' and so 'wait for idle' is redundant). 'Stop if the computer ceases to be idle' is also ticked along with 'Restart if the idle state resumes'.

This seems to work the first time the task is used properly but, thereafter, will be triggered after a few minutes. All in all, this never did what it what it was supposed to do..

So, I then tried to set the trigger as 'on event' and use the screensaver invoked event (I.d 4802) (with the standard screensaver timings etc.) but this event is not logged by default. I would have to enable logging of this event and the only way of doing this (which I can find) is to use the Group Policy Editor which, as some of you will know, does not come with Windows 10 Home as standard..

I've also tried other things that aren't worth mentioning.

If the reader could help me with my above attempts or provide a solution for my original intention without the use of 3rd party software, I will be very grateful.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found two pretty good articles that may help you. Seems like if you force the -s to run daily and set the timer to every hour it will cause it to shut off how you want. The second link shows how to do it with the sleep options.

[First Link](http://windowsreport.com/schedule-automatic-shutdown-windows-10/)

[Second Link](http://www.zerodollartips.com/set-auto-shutdown-sleep-windows-10/)

I would have just posted these in the comments but my score is so low I can't comment just answer.